# Getting an error while opening a Talend job?

Tags: talend, talend-mdm

While opening a talend job I am getting the following error. I am using talend 6.1.1

```
An error has occurred. See error log for more details.java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Note: when I double click on the job to open, the ln I am getting following window

[image]

How to resolve this error ?

Comment: Since we don't know any specifics, any configuration details or anything in what you were doing, please [edit] your question and add the text message from under "Details >>".

Comment: Hi i have editor just now

Comment: This is a start. Again, how does your configuration look like? Open Studio or Subscriber? Did the job work before? Can you open a new one? Did you take a look into the error log of Eclipse (https://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/reference/ref-error_log_view.htm)?